# waiting with code execution for input

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, dialog, electron

In an Electron application I need to alter an array of objects, I receive from an Excel File.

As long as there is no user Input in this functions this works great, but there is an option for the user to link a directory with filenames into that array.

If I open a dialog to choose the directory I'd need my script to stop and wait for the user input but can't see how to do that. Simplified my code looks like:

```
let initialArray = [];

let Arr1=[];
let Arr2=[];
let arrayFiles=[];

let outputData = [];

document.getElementById('importExcel').addEventListener('change', handleFile, false);

function handleFile(e) {
    //get initial Array an fill it with Data
    let q = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        for (let x of initialArray) {
            //extract Data for Arr1 and push it there
            //extract Data for Arr2 and push it there
        }
        resolve();
    }
    q.then(workOnArr1).then(getFiles).then(workOnArr1and2).then(mergeData).catch(console.log.bind(console));
}
function workOnArr1() {
    //rearranging and adding Data to Arr1
}
function getFiles() {
    if (document.getElementById("getFileData").checked) {
        dialog.showOpenDialog({properties: ['openDirectory']}, function (filePaths) {
            //here it should stop until a directory is chosen and the filenames
            // are read into arrayFiles
            fs.readdirSync(filePaths[0]).forEach(file => {
                arrayFiles.push(file)
            });
        });
    }
}
function workOnArr1and2() {
    //alter Arr1 and integrate the Data of arrayFiles into it
    for (let x of Arr1) {
        //that does not work, because the script does not stop at the dialog,
        //arrayFiles is always empty when this line is executed
        for (let y of arrayFiles) 
            if (somecondition) {
                x.subArray = y
            }
    }
    //alter and reshape Arr2
}
function mergeData() {
    outputData = _.concat(Arr1,Arr2);
    //write outputData to DB
}
```

As I understood chaining functions with `then`after a `Promise` waits for one function to finish before the next one is executed. But as it seems I missed some crucial points or may be completely wrong with my assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's **how** you deal with asynchronous code that is **important** to Promise chains - your `getFiles` function for example ... needs a Promise returned that resolves when the dialog is "done with"

```
function getFiles() {
    if (document.getElementById("getFileData").checked) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            dialog.showOpenDialog({properties: ['openDirectory']}, function (filePaths) { 
            //here it should stop until a directory is chosen and the filenames
            // are read into arrayFiles
                fs.readdirSync(filePaths[0]).forEach(file => {
                    arrayFiles.push(file)
                });
                // or better still
                //
                // arrayFiles.push(...fs.readdirSync(filePaths[0]))
                //
                resolve();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

One thing you're also doing that looks unconventional is, having a bunch of global objects that are updated in one function and read in the next, the beauty of Promises is not having to have such global pollution

e.g. a simplified example

```
Promise.resolve(5)
.then(x => x * 2)
.then(x => x - 1)
.then(x => x / 3)
```

instead of

```
let x = 5;
Promise.resolve()
.then(() => x = x * 2)
.then(() => x = x - 1)
.then(() => x = x / 3)
```

same result, but no need for variable `x`

Having said that, it may well be that what you are doing is the best way to do it, there's not really enough code to know what is happening, too much `// description of some vague functionality` in the question :p

Comment: That sounds extremely logical to me (I'm quite new to the idea of promises), but it does not change the behaviour. Adding this Promise does not stop the code afterwards to be executed before I choose a Folder.

Comment: Perhaps you did it wrong. Resolve on the wrong place? Did you return the promise?

Comment: You were absolute right. I just put the resolve into the wrong place. Now that I start understanding, I should rework a lot of my Code...